# How to print the value of a git latest_tag command in ruby / chef

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, chef-recipe, aws-opsworks

I'm trying to get the latest git tag from the git repo,which is clone to my EC2 Ubuntu instance. below is the chef recipe I'm using i.e git.rb

```
execute 'test' do
cwd 'myapp-codecommit/myfiles'
 #command 'git clone https://'+node[:awscli][:GIT_USER]+':'+node[:awscli][:GIT_PASS]+'@git-codecommit.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/xxxxxxxx'
  command '$(git describe --abbrev=0 --tags)'
  puts "output is #{command}"

end
```

output : EC2 Log

```
Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
output is $(git describe --abbrev=0 --tags)
[2018-07-13T12:04:28+00:00] INFO: Processing execute[test] action run 
Error executing action `run` on resource 'execute[test]'
Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed
Expected process to exit with [0], but received '127'
---- Begin output of $(git describe --abbrev=0 --tags) ----
STDOUT:
STDERR: sh: 1: master-1.0.177: not found
---- End output of $(git describe --abbrev=0 --tags) ----
Ran $(git describe --abbrev=0 --tags) returned 127
Resource Declaration:
# In /var/chef/runs/bb7cdd55-4fa8-4979-8485-dc5706d9db32/local-mode-cache/cache/cookbooks/deployfile/recipes/git.rb
3: execute 'test' do
4:     cwd 'myapp-codecommit/myfiles'
5:   #command 'git clone https://'+node[:awscli][:GIT_USER]+':'+node[:awscli][:GIT_PASS]+'@git-codecommit.us-east- 1.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/xxxxxxxx'
6:   command '$(git describe --abbrev=0 --tags)'
7:
8:   puts "output is #{command}"
9:
10: end
```

as we can see in the output log, I'm able to get the latest tag under (STDERR) i.e master-1.0.177
But I want the latest tag i.e (master-1.0.177)  to be printed as

`output is master-1.0.177`

where as I'm getting

```
output is $(git describe --abbrev=0 --tags)
```

Comment: It is unclear what you've tried and what you're asking, please clearly define the question.

Comment: Please edit your question (by clicking on the *edit* link directly below it)  and put the relevant code and error messages in there directly. Please do not post screenshots of code or error messages.

Comment: Hi @mjwatts , I want to get the value from the command and store it in a variable, but for the time being i just want it to display the value in puts.  writing to the stackoverflow for the first time bear with me and thanks for help

Comment: Hi @HolgerJust thanks for your help finally figured out how to get the code without the screenshot in the question. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chef resources do not have output values. What you probably want is some usage of the `shell_out!` helper method but you have to be more specific about what you are trying to accomplish in the end. Is this for some quick debugging?

EDIT:

You want something like this:

```
# You can swap in some other resource like s3_file, the principle is the same.
remote_file "download the artifact" do
  source lazy {
    git_describe = shell_out!('git describe --abbrev=0 --tags', cwd: '/path/to/myapp-codecommit/myfiles').stdout.strip
    "https://something/path/to/myapp-#{git_describe}.jar"
  }
end
```

Comment: so, I've stored the build artifacts in S3 and they are named as the git versions    e.g. master-1.0.177.jar , so i want to write a recipe which takes the latest git version and compares it with the build jar name and download that particular jar for deployment in opsworks. what could be the better way to do that ?

Comment: If you mean OpsWorks Stacks that does slightly complicate things as there is no version of Chef available there which is supported, but most of the same APIs exist. I'll edit in an example.

Comment: yes it worked for me only changes I made was in first line i.e. remote_file 'test.jar' file name with a jar extension and it worked fine :) thank you